# Value set /p in loop. In next step it remember variable from last step

Tags: loops, batch-file

I have some small code. Issue looks that on the next step program remember a value from last action despite I write new value. On next step it always get value from previous step. I try to clean this after task or before task, but then value is clean all time.

```
:BEGIN
cls
VER > NUL
echo #-------------------------------------------------#
SET /P PROGRAM=# Wybierz interesujacy cie program: 
echo #-------------------------------------------------#
2>NUL CALL :CASE_%PROGRAM%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL :CASE_DEFAULT

:CASE_6
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%I in (`powershell.exe`) do if "%%~$PATH:I" neq "" (
        set chooser=powershell "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.windows.forms|Out-Null;$f=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;$f.InitialDirectory='%windir%\System32\PSTools';$f.Filter='Executable Files (*.exe)|All Files (*.*)|*.*';$f.showHelp=$true;$f.ShowDialog()|Out-Null;$f.FileName"
    ) else (
    rem :: If not, compose and link C# application to open file browser dialog
        set chooser=%temp%\chooser.exe
        >"%temp%\c.cs" echo using System;using System.Windows.Forms;
        >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo class dummy{
        >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo public static void Main^(^){
        >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo OpenFileDialog f=new OpenFileDialog^(^);
        >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.InitialDirectory= "c:\\Windows\\System32\\PSTools\\";
        >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.Filter="Executable Files (*.exe)|*.exe|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.ShowHelp=true;
        >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.ShowDialog^(^);
        >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo Console.Write^(f.FileName^);}}
        for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /s "%windir%\microsoft.net\*csc.exe"') do (
            if not exist "!chooser!" "%%I" /nologo /out:"!chooser!" "%temp%\c.cs" 2>NUL
        )
        del "%temp%\c.cs"
        if not exist "!chooser!" (
            echo Error: Please install .NET 2.0 or newer, or install PowerShell.
            goto :EOF
        )
    )

    :: capture choice to a variable
    for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%chooser%') do set "filename=%%I"

    :: Clean up the mess
    del "%temp%\chooser.exe" 2>NUL

    IF "%filename%" == "C:\Windows\System32\PSTools\PsExec.exe" (
        SET /P COMPNAME="# Wybierz nazwe komputera: 
        echo # Podales: %COMPNAME%                             #
        echo #-------------------------------------------------#
        pause
        START "" %filename% -s \\%COMPNAME% cmd
    ) ELSE (
        echo # Inne narzedzia nie sa jeszcze obslugiwane.
        echo # Przepraszam
        #-------------------------------------------------#
        pause
    )
    set "COMPNAME="
    REM set "COMPNAME=%COMPNAME*=%"
    VER > NUL # reset ERRORLEVEL
    GOTO BEGIN
```

Comment: If you don't want to preserve the variable (just enter in set /p) you'll have to initialize the var first. `set "Program="&SET /P PROGRAM=# Wybierz interesujacy cie program: `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SET /P COMPNAME="# Wybierz nazwe komputera: 
    echo # Podales: !COMPNAME!                             #
    echo #-------------------------------------------------#
    pause
    START "" %filename% -s \\!COMPNAME! cmd
```

You need to use `!compname!` because you are varying the value of `compname` within the code block.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, this help. Can you explane me why this look like? Some Article about that. I need to reed more on difference between %var% and !var!

Comment: When a block of code (parenthesised sequence of commands) is parsed, any `%var%` is **REPLACED** by the actual value of `var` **at that time**, so when it is *executed*, any change to the value of `var` is not visible. Normally, `!var!` will display exactly that `!var!`, but if `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` has been executed, then `!var!` becomes the value of `var` as it is changed within the block. **Outside** of a code block, with `delayedexpansion` invoked, `%var%`=`!var!` Search SO for `delayed expansion` - hundreds of examples available.